# Squid3 - Cannot write log file

Tags: server, permissions, proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

Have trouble starting a newly installed squid (Squid 3.5.27 on Linux ubuntu-server 4.13.0-36-generic). Keep getting:

```
$ squid
WARNING: Cannot write log file: /var/log/squid/cache.log
/var/log/squid/cache.log: Permission denied
         messages will be sent to 'stderr'.
```

I have altered the permissions as follows (as per comments):

```
$ sudo chmod 644 /var/log/squid/cache.log
$ namei -l /var/log/squid/cache.log
f: /var/log/squid/cache.log
drwxr-xr-x root  root   /
drwxr-xr-x root  root   var
drwxrwxr-x root  syslog log
drwxr-xr-x proxy proxy  squid
-rw-r--r-- 755   proxy  cache.log
```

The user *proxy* is right? Have seen user *squid* referred to in some posts, but in the servers */etc/passwd*, only the user *proxy* is shown. After the changes, running squid with debug options:

```
$ squid -NCd1
WARNING: Cannot write log file: /var/log/squid/cache.log
/var/log/squid/cache.log: Permission denied
         messages will be sent to 'stderr'.
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
WARNING: Cannot write log file: /var/log/squid/cache.log
/var/log/squid/cache.log: Permission denied
         messages will be sent to 'stderr'.
2018/03/14 13:55:57| WARNING: Closing open FD    2
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Starting Squid Cache version 3.5.27 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu...
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Service Name: squid
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Process ID 4200
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Process Roles: master worker
2018/03/14 13:55:57| With 1024 file descriptors available
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Initializing IP Cache...
2018/03/14 13:55:57| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 8
2018/03/14 13:55:57| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 9
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Adding nameserver 127.0.0.53 from /etc/resolv.conf
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Adding domain WORKGROUP from /etc/resolv.conf
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
2018/03/14 13:55:57| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Store logging disabled
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Target number of buckets: 1008
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Using 8192 Store buckets
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Using Least Load store dir selection
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Finished loading MIME types and icons.
2018/03/14 13:55:57| HTCP Disabled.
fopen: Permission denied
2018/03/14 13:55:57| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Pinger socket opened on FD 16
2018/03/14 13:55:57| /var/run/squid.pid: (13) Permission denied
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Closing HTTP port [::]:3128
2018/03/14 13:55:57| Closing HTTPS port [::]:3130
FATAL: Could not write pid file
Squid Cache (Version 3.5.27): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.034 seconds = 0.022 user + 0.011 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 76608 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
2018/03/14 13:55:57| pinger: Initialising ICMP pinger ...
2018/03/14 13:55:57|  icmp_sock: (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 13:55:57| pinger: Unable to start ICMP pinger.
2018/03/14 13:55:57|  icmp_sock: (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 13:55:57| pinger: Unable to start ICMPv6 pinger.
2018/03/14 13:55:57| FATAL: pinger: Unable to open any ICMP sockets.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Using the proxy user for debugging (per comments), I get:

```
$ sudo -u proxy squid -NCd1
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Starting Squid Cache version 3.5.27 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu...
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Service Name: squid
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Process ID 4468
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Process Roles: master worker
2018/03/14 16:00:50| With 1024 file descriptors available
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Initializing IP Cache...
2018/03/14 16:00:50| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 9
2018/03/14 16:00:50| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 10
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Adding nameserver 127.0.0.53 from /etc/resolv.conf
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Adding domain WORKGROUP from /etc/resolv.conf
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
2018/03/14 16:00:50| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Store logging disabled
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Target number of buckets: 1008
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Using 8192 Store buckets
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Using Least Load store dir selection
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Finished loading MIME types and icons.
2018/03/14 16:00:50| HTCP Disabled.
2018/03/14 16:00:50| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Pinger socket opened on FD 17
2018/03/14 16:00:50| /var/run/squid.pid: (13) Permission denied
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Closing HTTP port [::]:3128
2018/03/14 16:00:50| Closing HTTPS port [::]:3130
FATAL: Could not write pid file
Aborted
```

Adding a squid.pid with chown proxy, gives me a running squid:

```
$ sudo -u proxy squid -NCd1
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Starting Squid Cache version 3.5.27 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu...
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Service Name: squid
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Process ID 4520
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Process Roles: master worker
2018/03/14 16:10:54| With 1024 file descriptors available
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Initializing IP Cache...
2018/03/14 16:10:54| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 9
2018/03/14 16:10:54| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 10
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Adding nameserver 127.0.0.53 from /etc/resolv.conf
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Adding domain WORKGROUP from /etc/resolv.conf
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
2018/03/14 16:10:54| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Store logging disabled
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Target number of buckets: 1008
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Using 8192 Store buckets
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Max Swap size: 0 KB
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Using Least Load store dir selection
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Set Current Directory to /var/cache/squid
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Finished loading MIME types and icons.
2018/03/14 16:10:54| HTCP Disabled.
2018/03/14 16:10:54| WARNING: no_suid: setuid(0): (1) Operation not permitted
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Pinger socket opened on FD 17
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Adaptation support is off.
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Accepting SSL bumped HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:3128 remote=[::] FD 14 flags=9
2018/03/14 16:10:54| Accepting NAT intercepted SSL bumped HTTPS Socket connections at local=[::]:3130 remote=[::] FD 15 flags=41
2018/03/14 16:10:55| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
```

Edited per comments.

Comment: Shouldn't squid be started as root ?

Comment: Or, preferably, as the `proxy` user. It seems you're running it as your user for debugging, so it cannot access some files that the squid service could have. Try `sudo -u proxy squid -NCd1` for debugging instead.

Comment: Thanks @muru. Question edited with results from using the proxy-user.

Answer (score 3):

`chown 755` ... did you mean `chmod 755`? You set the owner of the file to user with ID 755 (and presumably there is no such user). Revert it back to be owned by the `proxy` user:

```
sudo chown proxy /var/log/squid/cache.log
```

And a log file doesn't need execute permissions. `chmod 644` should be enough.

Comment: omg.. yes, chmod.

Comment: There is something else going on here, though, see edits above.

Answer (score -1):

Juts use this command

sudo chmod -R 1777 /var/log/squid/cache.log